# How to delete last 3 records in sequential file

Tags: cobol

I have n records in my sequential file and i have to delete last 3 records in the sequential file by using COBOL program. How can I do this?

Comment: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: In the SELECT ... ORGANIZATION IS xxxx? relative ?

Comment: there are a few tricks, but compiler and OS dependent. Please specify both.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are tricks, but none of them port over different Cobol compilers and different OS versions.

If you want to do it in the pure, totally portable Cobol style, read through the entire file buffering three records at a time, and write each record as it drops off the buffer.  When you hit end of file, just stop writing the buffered records and you will drop the last three.

Some Pseudo-Cobol might look like this:

```
   Perform Fill-Buffer
   Perform until End-Of-File
      Perform Write-Buffer
      Perform Fill-Buffer
   End-Perform
   .

Write-Buffer.
   Write OUTPUT-FILE 
    from The-Buffer (TOP-OF-BUFFER)
   End-Write
   .

Fill-Buffer.
* Do reads to fill a 3 position ring buffer
* and adjust TOP-OF-BUFFER to the current record...   
   .
```

This is actually something that is better done with a utility, like SORT.  But you can do it with Cobol.

Comment: +1 for suggesting that this isn't something that is worth writing a program for - use a utility!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the count of the file you are reading, or does it change each time you would run the program?

There is no simple way to do it without knowing the count. Otherwise you have to read the file twice, once for the count, the 2nd for storing the new updated records.

If space and memory aren't a major issue, table the entire file in working storage, then write the file back from the table, minus your last 3 records. That results in 1 time through the file and no extra reads or writes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing in a very efficient manner and faster by using dfssort utility as shown below. This just an example. Please change the record length and other parameters accordingly. Also, you need to count the number of records manually here.

```
//SORTT001 EXEC PGM=SORT                                                00100003
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*                                                 00110003
//SORTIN   DD  DSN=INPUT.FILE,DISP=SHR                                  00160003
//SORTOUT  DD  DSN=OUTPUT.FILE,                                         00170003
//             SPACE=(2790,(5376,1075),RLSE),                           00180003
//             UNIT=SYSSF,                                              00190003
//             DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=0080,BLKSIZE=0),                     00200003
//             DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE)                                  00210003
//SYSIN    DD  *                                                        00220003
 SORT FIELDS=COPY,STOPAFT=100                                           00230003
/*
```

Just count the number of records and update "STOPAFT=100" accordingly.Please let me know if you want a generalized solution.

Comment: Why would we need a generic solution? Everytime I've had to drop three records from a file, I've had exactly 103 records on the file, so I'm sure it'll be the same for everyone else. Don't specify LRECL and RECFM. SORT will do that. If you specify it in the JCL, there are two places to be aware of. As for efficient and faster, where are you getting the count from? Reading the file a second time?

Comment: From generic solution, I meant if the file records keep varying. Or if it required just for onetime. So, number of records can be counted manually, and last three can be ignored by using stopafter. I just gave an example. Yes, you are right, I made it too specific.

Comment: Counting by hand, or by eye, is not very effective either. Nor is browse/view and doing m-PF8. It's a fairly silly requirement, anyway. However, if you look at ICETOOL you should find something generic enough. SUBSET is a clue.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. From now onwards, I will keep in mind your tips.